# Unable to load css into my views in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have included my css into application folder in codeigniter
 Folders:
     system
      application
     application/css/style.css

I am unable to load the my view file if I include css file like this
     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>`

What could be the reason? Please help me to solve this issue.

```
        <html>
        <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table width="100%" border="1" >
                <td   align="left"><h1>hellooooooo</h1></td>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When you view the source of the HTML what's the value of the href attribute?

Comment: lookt at the generated html code and u will see wrong path to the css file

Comment: @David i get only upto `<html><head>`

Comment: @vlcekmi3 generated html code shows only ` <html><head> `   . I after this it skips remaining codes

Comment: When you go to the page in your browser and view the page source you should see at least `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />` between the `<head></head>` tags.

Comment: @David  No its not showing. its only showing `<html><head>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the Css folder in the root   and writing the below code in php page. Solved my issue.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`

Answer (score 0):

base_url() should refer to your URL like yoursite.com/. so it likely not pointing to the code igniter directory. try putting your css in your home directory like yoursite.com/css/style.css I believe this is also what is suggested on codeigniters site.

however if you feel best to leave it where it is use   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/yourcodeigniterfolderlocation/application/css/style.css' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't keep css in the application folder.It should be outside the application folder.

If you Project name is project then create a folder named css in project and keep all your css there. To access those css you path will be `<?php echo base_url().'css/filename.css' ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file has to be in a public-accessible folder, which is (hopefully) not the case with your `application` and `system` folders.

Your assets have to be besides your index.php like so:

```
- index.php
- css/
    - style.css
```

Then in your view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css') ?>">
```